# Draw horizontal and vertical lines collapsing at mouse position

Tags: javascript

I am tying to draw horizontal and vertical line collapsing at mouse position. I am facing two problems

1. Horizontal line is not showing up. Seems like some CSS issue but could not figure out.
2. While moving mouse the redrawing of lines is not smooth. Its cluttering. Anyway I can avoid that?

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rkkghrvL/4/)

Code:

```
var element = document.getElementById('box');

var drawLines = function(event) {
  var x = event.pageX;
  var y = event.pageY;

  var straightLine = element.querySelector('.straightLine');
  var hrLine = element.querySelector('.hrLine');

  var slTrans = 'translate(' + x + 'px, 0px)';
  var hrTrans = 'translate(0px, ' + y + 'px)';
  if(!straightLine) {
     straightLine = document.createElement('div');
     straightLine.classList.add('straightLine');
     straightLine.style.height = "100%";
     straightLine.style.width = '2px';
     element.appendChild(straightLine);
  }
  straightLine.style.transform = slTrans;

  if(!hrLine) {
     hrLine = document.createElement('div');
     hrLine.style.height = "2px";
     hrLine.classList.add('hrLine');
     hrLine.style.width = '100%';
     element.appendChild(hrLine);
  }
  hrLine.style.transform = hrTrans;
}

element.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
   drawLines(event);
});

element.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
   drawLines(event);   
});

element.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event) {
   drawLines(event);
});

element.addEventListener('mouseout', function(event) {
   drawLines(event);
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The horizontal line issue can be fixed with:

```
.straightLine, .hrLine {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
}
```

See updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rkkghrvL/7/).

**EDIT**
You can also use the following to smooth out the animation (you'll have to adjust the timespan to suit your needs:

```
.straightLine, .hrLine {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
    transition: transform .05s ease-in-out;
}
```

See updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rkkghrvL/8/) and [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp).

Comment: Thanks, looks like fiddle problem.

Comment: @adamdc Adding animation makes sense. But it does not move as fast as the mouse :)

Comment: @Exception The mouse movement isn't always going to be smooth (mine's very jerky with my sensitivity settings), adding a transition will allow you to compensate for that.  A shorter timing or different transition-timing-function can get you closer to the result you're after.  Even without the transition the animation trails behind the mouse (and is pretty smooth for me).